# how to disable this type of file can harm your computer in pupeteer

Tags: javascript, automation, chromium

hey I m automating a website and I need to download some files from it

but when I try to download it this message pops everytime "this type of file can harm your computer"

any way to disable it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch the browser with a `--webview-disable-safebrowsing-support` argument

```
this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ["--webview-disable-safebrowsing-support"],
});
```

More Chrome arguments are listed [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).